# Resharper 6.0 - context action discards comments

Tags: resharper

When context action such as *convert if to switch* is invoked, all my comments are lost. Can this be prevented?

e.g.:

```
        int a = 1;
        int i;
        if (a == 1)
            //comment I want to keep 1
            i = 1;
        else if (a == 2)
            //comment I want to keep 2
            i = 2;
        else
            i = 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a known issue - here it is on YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-115681) (and [here's a duplicate](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-126544)).

Comment: thanks, couldn't find it... too bad this hasn't been fixed for 2 years... quite cripples the function